# how to acess json result in jquery for form plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am using jquery form plugin for file upload . my question is how to access the jsonresult from the controller in the script part of view using jquery.
my script is as

```
 $(function() {
       $("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
               iframe: true,
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                target :"myTable",
               url: "/UploadFile/Index",
             success: function(response,statusText)  {
        var jsonObject= result.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
       for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
               alert(response.filesList[i]);
                   $('#myTable').append('<tr><td> <a href=' + response.filesList[i] + '></a> td></tr>');
               }
        }
    }
      })
 })
```

and in my controller takes filename and adds to static list type string filesList and returns as jsonresult type

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public JsonResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
    string filename = file.FileName;
                filesList.Add(filename);
   return new JsonResult
        { ContentType = "text/plain",
            Data = Json(new
                {
                 filesList = filesList.Select(x => "File uploaded successfully " + x)
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        };
}
```

But i think it is wrong representation of handling json result in script, what i want it to do is append filesList to table ,for that how to handle jsonresult object in script.

thanking you,
michaeld

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the json in the success function? try to console.log it with firebug installed

Comment: yeah nicola the success function  is represented in wrong way, i have added to put an idea ,but i am not clear what exactly to be written is json success that itself is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your problem, first you should rewrite controller. Why would you need text/html when returning json? And string + list of strings is impossible, i guess you want the list of the messages and file names

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                List<String> fileNames = new List<string>();

            fileNames.Add(file.FileName);


            return Json(new
            {
                FileNames = fileNames.Select(x=> "File uploaded successfully " + x)
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then on client side, directly use the `result` object, as you set the dataType = 'json', it is already the json object

```
success: function(result) {
       for (i = 0; i < result.FileNames; i++) {
       $('#myTable').append('<tr><td> <a href=' + result.FileNames[i] + '></a> td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi archil, i want to try this in my code, but unfortunatley i was struck at fileNames.Select  as List<String> does not contain definition for Select. what can i do? also what JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet actually does?

Comment: add the using System.Linq; to your class

Comment: ok added , but why after i submit i am getting a popup save file  window of type Application/json , suppose if i say save it is saving with name of the button ,even table is also not generated

Comment: hi archil, since the return type is json object we are getting popup ,even if i comment the success also i am geting that popup.

Comment: First, there was some mistake in my answer that i corrected, when using dataType = 'json' in form, JSON.parse is not needed. Second, i repeat the exactly same situation on my machine and it is working fine, no any windows or file saves. You should examine your code to see what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe you could post your form code in here? Save window may be the situation when there's mistake in jQuery binding to form submit and the form is submitted without ajax

Comment: first, if i add alert(result.FileNames[i]); in for loop it's not hitting. Second,in controller return we should add  contenttype to avoid popup, since the form is submitting it is expecting html rather than json,for this i think to update as ajax submit? how can that be done? but i think it is already ajax submit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are attaching to a table with id mytable a lot of table rows. I don't understand exactly what you want, i try to guess.
If you want to append a list of filename i think you should do:

```
   var jsonObject= result.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
   var html = '<ul>';
   for (i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
      html += '<li> <a href=' + jsonObject[i].message + '></a> </li>'
    }
     html += '</ul>';
     $('#mytable').after(html);
}
```

Comment: Hi nicola , after adding the above code for submit , instead of getting the table  i am getting a save fileas popup window with filename as button name ,what might be problem , ithink it is because of json object, how can i avoid that popup and show the table?

Comment: the problem is because of return type in controller , for this success function type what should be the dataType in jquery and return type in controller.